# Deleting rows from listview bases on a value for a column

Tags: asp.net

I got a datatable in list view.

ID      TelcoName    Reload Value(RM)   Quantity    Total(RM)
1           Maxis             5            1          5         Delete
2           Digi              5            1          5         Delete

This is basically what my table looks like.
My html code is this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnSorting="ListView1Sorting" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
                                <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                                    <th align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server">Id &nbsp;</asp:Label></th>
                                    <th align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server">TelcoName&nbsp;</asp:Label></th>
                                    <th align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblReloadValue" runat="server">Reload Value(RM)&nbsp;</asp:Label></th>
                                    <th align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server">Quantity&nbsp;</asp:Label></th>
                                    <th align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server">Total (RM)&nbsp;</asp:Label></th>                                    
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                               <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId"><%#Eval("ID") %></asp:Label></td>
                        <td align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTelcoName"><%#Eval("TelcoName") %></asp:Label></td>
                        <td align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblReloadValue"><%#Eval("ReloadValue")%></asp:Label></td>
                        <td align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuantity"><%#Eval("Quantity")%></asp:Label></td>
                        <td align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"><%#Eval("Total")%></asp:Label></td>
                        <td align="center"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
                        </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

This is my behind code for deleting:

Protected Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs)
     If (e.CommandName) = "Sort" Then
            Dim txteno As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ID"), Label)
            Dim deletecommand As String = "delete from dt where ID=" & Convert.ToInt32(txteno.text)
            Session("dt").DeleteCommand = deletecommand
        End If
    End Sub

My problem here is i coud'nt get the ID of the row which the user choose. The "ID" is the name of the first column but when i run the website, this statement return nothing.

Dim txteno As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ID"), Label)

My question is how do i retrieve the value of the column("Id") to use for the deleting data? i ask around and someone suggest to me to use e.item.DataItemIndex but i coudnt find this command anywhere. Any idea how to solve this?

This has just been added

Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim i = 0
        Dim ID As New DataColumn("ID")
        dt.Columns.Add(ID)
        Dim TelcoName As New DataColumn("TelcoName")
        dt.Columns.Add(TelcoName)
        Dim ReloadValue As New DataColumn("ReloadValue")
        dt.Columns.Add(ReloadValue)
        Dim Quantity As New DataColumn("Quantity")
        dt.Columns.Add(Quantity)
        Dim Total As New DataColumn("Total")
        dt.Columns.Add(Total)
        ListView1.DataSource = dt
        ListView1.DataBind()
        Session("dt") = dt

After i binded to the listview, do i need to delcare a name for the datatable so that i can use it as a reference for sql statement or i can just leave it as dt and in sql statement, when i refer to dt, it refer to the table in the listview?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Addressing two questions separately - one is that a control handle could not be grabbed, the other question is around deleting from a DataTable

**Control Reference**

If you're trying to get a handle on the control using this:

```
Dim txteno As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ID"), Label)
```

Then I think the control ID is incorrect as in your markup you've defined it as "lblId". So perhaps try:

```
 Dim txteno As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblId"), Label)
```

Also, I'm not sure what impact it would have but I would give the  controls in the LayoutTemplate (so I am guessing the header for your ListView) different ID's to the  controls in your ItemTemplate, if only for maintenance/cleanliness if nothing else.

The label should also be bound like:

```
<asp:Label id="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
```

So that in code-behind the text can be retrieved.

**Deleting from DataTable**

Based on the poster's comments, the DataTable's data is not coming from a database.

Since you aren't connecting back to a database, you don't have to write SQL to remove items from the DataTable.

It looks like you're storing the DataTable in session. And also that you are binding totally in code. As such, what you could do in your ItemCommand method is:

1. Iterate over the data table to find the item to delete
2. Delete the item (you could consult, for example, [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1300651.aspx) forum post)
3. Once the item has been removed from the DataTable, re-bind it to the list view. As an example of someone who seems to have been in a similar situation please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723307/how-to-delete-a-item-in-a-asp-net-listview-and-persist-the-datasource)

HTH,
Nathan

Comment: i do as you suggested and change from "ID" to "lblID" but im still unable to return the row index that i needed. What i receive is just blank for lblID. Someone told me that it is because DirectControl only works on rendering time in the ListView_ItemDataBound method.. May i knows what does that means? i still coudnt find that method by the way.

Comment: Hi there, did you use "lblID" or "lblId" - it'll be case sensitive. I'll respond to your other questions as best I can in a separate comment....

Comment: Re: e.Item.DataItemIndex, which version of .NET are you working with? If you look at the doc for [ListViewCommandEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewcommandeventargs.item.aspx) it has an Item property which has type ListViewItem. If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.dataitemindex.aspx) at ListViewItem, the DataItemIndex property is only available in .NET 4 or 4.5...could that be why you can't find the method?

Comment: i use lblid and i use .NET 3.5. It said my input string is incorrect format cause my txteno returns "".

Comment: Ah OK...Yes, the Text property is empty because you're not setting it in your label but just inserting a value inside <asp:Label></asp:Label>.

Try something like:

<asp:Label id="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>

Note here that the ID is being set to the Text property so you should, hopefully, be able to get its value in your ItemCommand method

Comment: ok this time i got it and it works but i have another error. it prompt out saying that 'Public member 'DeleteCommand' on type 'DataTable' not found.' May i know what is the error here? is the error occur because i didnt declare the table name in the list view? Read my edit for the datatable creation and inserting into listview.

Comment: Where is the data in the DataTable coming from? Is it coming from a database or is it coming from another source? Also, it might be worthwhile for you to go through this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337898.aspx) as it has sample code and walks you through the ListView basics. The article is a bit old but it is targeted at .NET 3.5, which you said you were on

Comment: my data in the datatable comes from data that are insertby user's. it is not from any database

Comment: I have put some additional information in my answer which I hope will help point you in the right direction. I would still suggest going through the tutorial I linked in a previous comment but otherwise you might get better help by splitting off your issue about deleting from the DataTable into a separate question on the site

Comment: i use some different technique but eventually i manage to do it. Hoorayy!!!!haha. What i did is i delete the data straight from the datatable before rebinding it into the listview instead of deleting the data from listview itself.

Comment: I'm glad you worked your way to a solution. Please consider closing the question or otherwise marking it as answered if you found the help you got here useful :-) Good job, again, on getting your way to a solution